# unable to download apps from Google play store using mobile data

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I am using letv and i am trying to download Google applications from play store when i click on install it displays "waiting for wifi"
I am using mobile data but it's not downloading through mobile data .
How can i download through mobile data

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the internet through your browser? If you don't have internet access at all, your mobile networks settings are probably incorrect.
Try changing the Network mode and then under Network operators tap Select automatically.
You can also try contacting your service provider.